# How big is Godzilla in the new film?

Tags: pacific-rim, godzilla-2014, monsterverse

I'm trying to work out if the Godzilla in the latest film is biggest yet and how it compares to Pacific Rim's Kaiju.

I know [Scunner](http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Scunner) (the only Cat V kaiju) was 134.4m and weighed 3,230 tons. Although we never saw it out of the water so it's hard to judge against the cityscape.

Are there any figures on the various sizes of Godzilla across the years?

Comment: Uh ... ***Big***? ;-)

Comment: @AndrewThompson that's why I referenced Scunner specifically

Comment: Oh crap..  Got to practice that entire 'read all the way through the 2nd sentence' thing.  :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a good enough answer for you, as it doesn't contain weight, but among the promotional material released for Godzilla was this **size comparison chart**:

[image]

Now, to my understanding that is an official chart, released in **Empire Magazine**. It lists him as being just **over 100m** tall.

I've also seen this fan-made chart which differs slightly:

[image]

It lists him as being between **120 and 150 meters** tall.

Comment: So Scunner was actually bigger!? I didn't see that coming!

Comment: I think I have read various reviews to talk about more than 300 metres, but maybe this was a mistranslation of feet.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: It could be, but I've definitely read different sources of information about his height. I'd be most trusting of the slightly above 100m answer, as that was released by the film creators.

Comment: This is an easy one ... like most lizards, he's grown bigger over time. In the first reference it does appear that the big (bigger) guy is slouching, so the 120-150m approximation is not out of the question.